# expected integer, found `&{integer}`

Tags: rust, iterator

I learn iterators and exactly speaking copied code below, and got error:

> expected integer, found `&{integer}`

```
let v = [1, 2, 3];
let mut iter = v.into_iter();

assert_eq!(Some(1), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some(2), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some(3), iter.next());
assert_eq!(None, iter.next());
```

Appreciate explanation what I do wrong, while copied code from documentation does not work. The error I got the every those lines:

```
assert_eq!(Some(1), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some(2), iter.next());
assert_eq!(Some(3), iter.next());
```

Below information about `rustc`:

```
tomek@rhei-box:~/workspaces/rust-learn$ rustc --version
rustc 1.67.0 (fc594f156 2023-01-24)
```

Source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#examples

Comment: For which line?

Comment: Looks like you just need to dereference the pointer to the integer to get the integer

Comment: You might be using an older toolchain, where `v.into_iter()` will return references instead of values. Can you post the output of `rustc --version`?

Comment: Time for a `rustup check` I'd expect.

Comment: Do you have `edition = "2021"` in your `Cargo.toml`? If you don't then you get the old behavior where `.into_iter()` on arrays yields references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you're missing an `edition` key in your `Cargo.toml` since [`IntoIterator` is only implemented for references to arrays for Rust versions prior to 1.54](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/IntoIterator-for-arrays.html), therefore in editions before `2021` the `IntoIterator` implementation for arrays is hidden to preserve the semantics of older code, so to fix this you can add the following/replace the existing `edition` in your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
//…
edition = "2021"
```